# In android ART system, JIT cached compiled native code only in memory or on disk

Tags: android, jit

Dalvik VM using JIT to optimize app performance. In android 5.0 and 6.0 system JIT is removed. However, in android 7.0, it is introduced again.

My question is JIT cached compiled native code only in memory or on disk. If it is on disk, could the cached Jit compiled native code be resued?